Transfer gestures to view on other UIWindow?
I have a set-up in my iOS app where I have two UIScreens (and thus two UIWindows) - one on the device, and the other on an external display.
I want the user to be able to make a gesture on their device that could then be transferred to a UIView on the external screen.
For example, if the user scrolls on the view on their screen, I could transfer it to scroll a UIScrollView on the other. I do not want to use mirroring, that solution doesn't work for my use case, as there are still differences between the two views. I only want to pass touches.
Other solutions I've found seem to only involve views that are placed directly behind the one receiving the touches, so I'm not sure what to do here. I assume a UIKit solution would include UIGestureRecognizer or similar?
Could anyone point me in the right direction here?
Thanks!

I suspect there is not a simple off-the-shelf way to do this. You'd have to implement a linked pair of custom gesture recognizers. That would be one way to go.
Another thing you could do is to write your views using a layer of abstraction, where there is an interface that takes input from something like gesture recognizers through your own interface. The first view would have gesture recognizers on it, which would pass the user's inputs into it directly, and it would also hand the user's inputs on to the second view.
I don't have any examples to give you. I am proposing novel solutions that you would have to develop yourself. (Unless you get lucky and can find an open source library somebody else has written.)
